# Get only last 2 array using Foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP foreach() return only last 50 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680406/php-foreach-return-only-last-50-items)

I need only the last 2 record from it.
The code below return all the records. thank you

```
<?php 
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $type = $field['s_type'];
        $label = $field['s_label'];
        $value = Attributes::newInstance()->getValue($item_id, $field['pk_i_id']);
        if ($type == 'checkbox') {
            if ($value == 'checked') $value = 'Yes';
            else $value = 'No';
        }
?>
        <tr>
            <td style='width: 150px;'><?php _e($label, pg); ?></td>
            <td style='width: 150px;'><?php _e($value, pg); ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: sorry the $fileds is from a funtion as below     $fields = Attributes::newInstance()->getFields();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you use array_slice with -2 as the second parameter?

Comment: Thanks Hakre for your help it was the one I was looking for                  foreach (array_slice($fields, -2) as $field) {

Comment: @user1956624 don't use that unless you want calculate the sliced array each iteration...

Comment: I found the duplicate in the list of related questions on the right. Just search a little you will find answers more quickly ;) - And also see the hint by Austin in his answer, about you should query the database in a way that you only get the last two back. That's how it should be done for database queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array slice to manage the fields before iterating.

```
$last_two = array_slice($fields, -2);

foreach($last_two as $field) { ... }
```

Although if this is the only thing being done in this script I would suggest rewriting your query structure.